# Can i set href width and height 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to create a menu with a background image and text in the center with 100% width and height properties.

I have such code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
          <div><a class="aMenuHref" href="#">My Link</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

.aMenuHref{
    font-size: large;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/back1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0px;
  }
  #wrapper > #container {
    display: table;
    position: static;
  }
  #container div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  }
  #container div div {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
  }
  #container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: static;
  }
#container:hover{
    background: orange;
}
```

But my href hasn't `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a>` hasn't width and height 100% because of the `<body>`.

You can reset the body with:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then you can achieve height 100% with:

```
html, body, #wrapper, #container, #container div, .aMenuHref {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Center the text horizontally:

```
.aMenuHref {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And vertically:

```
.aMenuHref {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;  
}
```

The final code will look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body, #wrapper, #container, #container div, .aMenuHref {
  height: 100%;
}

.aMenuHref{
    font-size: large;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/back1.jpg) no-repeat 0 0px;
}

#container:hover{
    background: orange;
}    

</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
          <div><a class="aMenuHref" href="#">My Link</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```